# How to allow "half windows" in biopython?

Tags: phylogenetics, proteins, python, sequence-analysis, phylogeny

I am using Biopython to examine protein sequences including the Kyte and Doolittle hydrophobicity. However, for short sequences, this returns an empty value; the value is not allowed if the window does not have 20 values.

```
from Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam import ProteinAnalysis

window_length=20
edge=1
kyte = {'A': 1.8, 'R': -4.5, 'N': -3.5, 'D': -3.5, 'C': 2.5, 'Q': -3.5, 'E': -3.5, 'G': -0.4, 'H': -3.2, 'I': 4.5,
        'L': 3.8, 'K': -3.9, 'M': 1.9, 'F': 2.8, 'P': -1.6, 'S': -0.8, 'T': -0.7, 'W': -0.9, 'Y': -1.3, 'V': 4.2}

full_sequence_analysis = ProteinAnalysis("CYGTGAVYLLGLGIGGFS")
kyte_window = full_sequence_analysis.protein_scale(kyte, window_length, edge)
```

Is there are a built in Biopython option in this for "allow half windows/short windows" for incomplete windows? There is nothing I can see to suggest so in [the docs](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqUtils.ProtParam-pysrc.html#ProteinAnalysis.protein_scale).

Comment: @Chris_Rands This would fix the error. However, it would change the absolute values. Ideally, I would like to keep the window length at ±10 residues (up to 20 residues) if possible.

Comment: Have you tried odd values for window_length? https://web.expasy.org/protscale/ allows 3 5 7 ... 21

Comment: @nicolallias The issue would still remain. Even if I had 3 residue window length when I sample the final residue in the sequence, there are only 2 residues available for the window (the final residue, and the preceding residue), so no value is generated because 3 residues are needed for the windowed value.

Answer (score 3):

You can choose between a `window_size` of 20 for sequences longer than 20 AAs, and the length of the sequence for those shorter::

```
seq = "CYGTGAVYLLGLGIGGFS"
window_length = min(len(seq), 20)

full_sequence_analysis = ProteinAnalysis(seq)
kyte_window = full_sequence_analysis.protein_scale(kyte, window_length, edge)
```